Neo4j openshift Websocket connection failure
I deployed the Neo4j Docker image on Openshift.
This is my deployment:
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: neo4j-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: neo4j
      containers:
        - resources: {}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          name: neo4j
          env:
            - name: NEO4J_AUTH
              value: neo4j/12345678
            - name: NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT
              value: 'yes'
            - name: NEO4J_server_config_strict__validation_enabled
              value: 'false'
            - name: SERVICE.PORT.BOLT
              value: '7687'
            - name: dbms.connector.bolt.advertised_address
              value: '0.0.0.0:7687'
            - name: dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address
              value: '0.0.0.0:7687'
            - name: dbms.connector.bolt.enabled
              value: 'true'
            - name: dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level
              value: OPTIONAL
          ports:
            - containerPort: 7474
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 7687
              protocol: TCP
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          volumeMounts:
            - name: neo4j-data
              mountPath: /data
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          image: 'neo4j:latest'
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      securityContext: {}
      schedulerName: default-scheduler


The service with ports 7474 and 7687 is okay. I generated two routes for each port. When I try to access using bolt://route:7687, I get this error: WebSocket connection to 'ws:/' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
I also tried using neo4j://.
Any ideas how to fix that?
Thanks

I don't know if this will fix your problem, but I do see some errors in your configuration.

Bash doesn't recognise environment variables with . characters in them, so to pass these configurations to Neo4j via environment you need to change them a little. The documentation is here. For example, dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true would be NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_enabled=true.
Configuration settings starting dbms.connector.* are renamed since 5.0. You need to do server.* instead. Documentation. For example dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true in Neo4j 5.x docker should be NEO4J_server_bolt_enabled=true. This will be why you're getting configuration validation errors.

Aside from that, the default values for these settings are:

server.bolt.enabled=true
server.bolt.listen_address=:7687
server.bolt.advertised_address=:7687

so you probably don't need to be configuring bolt at all.
